# Windows Phone emulator with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am creating a Xamarin project, and I made it working with Android and iOS, but I can't figure out how to start the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator. 
Windows Phone 8.1 is created as a project just like the other platforms.

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Community and Xamarin Business.

**EDIT**
I made it running by setting it as startup project, but are there others way by e.g. changing the project (where you choose if it is debug or release)?

I also want to know, how I can create the application to Windows store

Comment: the windows phone project is selected as "startup project"?

Comment: It worked, but how can I create an app for the store?

Comment: @LasseMadsen Can you exactly tell me your issue.  Are you not able to run the Windows phone app using win phone emulator? Hope you are able to run the android app and ios app  using their respective emulators

Comment: Do You have phone sdk installed and hyper-v activated?

Comment: Yes, I have both installed Phone SDK and activated Hyper-V

Comment: Try to start emulator from windows phone power tools.. Maybe it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create app package go to 
Project->Store->Create App Package - It will open wizard for creating app package that You are able to send to store (reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975357.aspx)

As for the other ways:[image: Visual Studio 2015 - choose debug/release, CPU architecture, startup project, where to deploy an app - eg. emulator or device]

In Visual Studio 2015 You can choose in taskbar: debug/release, CPU architecture, **startup project** and **where to deploy an app - eg. emulator or device**